# MySQL: Select TIMEDIFF values where the difference is greater than x

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(start, end) AS difference
```

The above value would return `00:10:00` if the start and end values were `01:05:00`, `01:15:00`.

How can I change my SQL statement so that it only selects differences that are greater than `00:05:00`?

Comment: Try `WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(start, end)) > 300`

Comment: @Mihai Thanks so much for your help! Yesterday I wrote one of the most complex SQL queries I have ever wrote.. today I can't even write the simplest :-P

Comment: @Mihai That should be an answer - put it there, and I'd gladly upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(start, end)) > 300
```